# Prove the following lemma of propositional logic: (A1 ∨ · · · ∨ Ak) ∧ (A1 → B) ∧ · · · ∧ (Ak → B) |= B.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How do I prove the following lemma of propostional logic:

$(A_1 \vee \ldots \vee A_k) \wedge (A_1 \rightarrow B) \wedge \ldots \wedge (A_k \rightarrow B) \vDash B$

I tried proving it with induction. The base case k = 1 is fairly easy to prove. Unfortunately I sturggle proving the induction step.
Maybe its not the right approach?

Comment: Use an argument based on the "logic" of truth table: when $(A_1 \lor \ldots  \lor A_k)$ is True?

Comment: Is it a logic course? An introductory math course? What have you tried? In your class, how are similar exercices solved?

Comment: Compare with [Proof by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).

Comment: Do you know how to prove it for $k=2$?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I believe that the key for induction is to prove the case $k=2,$ and to rewrite it$$[(A_1\to B)\land(A_2\to B)]\to[(A_1\lor A_2)\to B],$$in order to use it for the induction step.

Comment: two words: disjunctive elimination